# How to display in <pre> element an Array (object), which is displayed in console.log?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, console.log

Hi I want to display my Array named allDomains in `<pre></pre>` element. I have a console.log with it, but how to get it in html preformatted block? I've checked - my Array is an object.

I have included my console.log(allDomains) view.

[image: ript]

Comment: do you want that pre-formatted HTML in console or in the UI?

Comment: Did you want it as <pre>["x", "y", "z"]</pre>?

Comment: Exacly, but maybe in more readable version <pre>x \n y \n z</pre>

Comment: You can't do this.

Comment: Why? is any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) 3rd argument to force that.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="triggerButton">Display domain objects</button>

    <pre id="placeholder"></pre>

    <script>
      function showArrayInHTML() {
        var domains = [
          'asdasd',
          'bfbfbf',
          '234234243',
          'zxcxcxzc',
        ];
        
        var result = domains.map(function(domain, index) {
          return index + ': ' +domain;
        });
        
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 1);
      }
          
      document.getElementById('triggerButton').addEventListener('click', showArrayInHTML);
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you need how to learn how to be helped. Do you expect others to guess what is not working? If you run that code snippet, does it work?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but like You see I have an Array which looks like this: [0:"x", 1:"y", 2:"x", ......]

Comment: This is the closest I can get.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<pre id="array_placeholder"></pre>` in your html.
In your javascript, iterate through the array and set the `<pre>` element's innerHTML. For example:

```
document.getElementById('array_placeholder').innerHTML = formatArrayString(allDomains);
```

You can define `formatArrayString()` as a function that accepts the array as a parameter and formats it into the string you want to display.

Example demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to join the array elements into a string.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<pre id="demo"></pre>
<pre id="demo2"></pre>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.innerHTML = fruits.join('\n');
  
  var allDomains = {0: "first.com", 2: "second.com", 3: "third.com"};
  var y = document.getElementById("demo2");
  y.innerHTML = Object.entries(allDomains).map(o => o[1]).join('\n');
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could You give me a solution for that function? I'm beginner in js :D

Comment: @Wojtek, see my edited response. Replace fruits with allDomains.

Comment: but, like I said I have and array wich is an object and that statndard solution doesn't work in that case

Comment: Your console.log() screenshot is showing [] (which is array) not {} (which is object)

Comment: i get empty results in html view with that solution :/

Comment: Please create a minimal code sample of what is not working as intended and post here so people can look at it and say what is wrong and suggest fixes.

Comment: @Wojtek, please check the snippet. I think you perhaps have an object that is keyed with integer values (based on your console.log).